# Opened Transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions, commit

When I execute this very simple statement:

```
update
    c
set
    c.StrukturID = vs.Verbandstrukturid
from
    adcodes_sql as c 
inner join 
    Verbandstruktur as vs on vs.HcAdresscode = c.Codes_Gruppe
where
    vs.Strukturtypintern = 3 and
    c.Strukturid <> vs.Verbandstrukturid
```

just as that, something strange happens. Without open a new transaction with `begin tran` SQL Server seems to open a transaction. If I don't write "commit" under the statement, the table is locked. I use that script several times on different customer environments and I'm facing this issue just on this one server. What could be the reason for that behaviour? I've got no clue.

Thank you. 
Reto

Comment: SQL Server will **always** run an `UPDATE` statement in a transaction - either in your *explicitly* defined transaction (using `BEGIN TRAN`), or if that's not around, then SQL Server uses an **implicit** transaction for the statement. The `UPDATE` statement will lock those rows it affects - those rows being updated - it will **not** lock the whole table (unless your `UPDATE` affects more than 5000 rows at once - then a lock escalation to a table lock applies)

Comment: Sounds like you may have [`IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187807.aspx) set.